# How do I partition new disk space after upgrading instance type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I had created a `t1.micro` instance with an EBS volume attached to it. The volume was 8 GB. I stopped the instance and changed instance type to [`m1.medium`](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) which should have 410 GB of instance storage. When I do `df -h` on the instance, my output is

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.9G  1.5G  6.4G  19% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
```

Is there a way to partition/mount the 410 GB to the EBS volume? Or how can I get the rest of the instance storage to my use? (I'd like it to be part of the EBS so I it will be included in the snapshots)

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize your file system.  You won't be able to do in your current instance because `/dev/xvda1` is the root file system.  What you have to do is shutdown your instance, detach the `/dev/xvda1` EBS volume from the instance.

Then, create a new instance and attach the EBS volume you detached above as say `/dev/xvdf`. Then run:

```
e2fsck -f /dev/xvdf
resizefs /dev/xvdf
```

Test it by doing the following:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/xvdf
mount /dev/xvdf /mnt/xvdf
df -h
```

Umount it:

```
umount /dev/xvdf
```

Then, shutdown that newly created instance and detatch the `/dev/xvdf` EBS volume. Next, you can attach this EBS volume to original instance as `/dev/xvda1`, start your instance and you should have `root` disk with 410GB.

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

The 410 GB is instance storage. It can only be attached when the instance is launched for the first time, not after its been upgraded. You will need to create an image from your current instance and launch it as a new instance to enable instance storage.

Keep in mind, instance storage is not EBS storage. It does not persist.

If you want EBS storage, you can create and attach new EBS volumes of any size you prefer. But you will pay for the provisioned size of the volume.